# static Array in typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, static

Hi I am new to Typescript and I need to use static array in my code. But when I declared array as follows

```
private static arrayname:String[];
```

When I typed `this.` it didn't show me the array name so I can't able to push any values into this array. Can any one help me in this?

Comment: If you want to use this for a static variable then I guess you should start thinking about reading the basics again.... Anyway String in typescript is normally low-case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use class name instead of "this":

```
class A {
    private static arrayname: string[] = ["a", "b", "c"];

    someFunc(): number {
        return A.arrayname.length; // Here I'm calling private statis property
    }
}


var instanceA = new A();
alert(instanceA.someFunc());
```

This code works for me in the [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/).

#### Note

You can use private member inside class functions only. It isn't accessible and visible outside the class declared in.

Comment: I tried that too my class name is Sample but when I tried Sample. it doesn't shows the array name

Comment: now I can push data but I want it to use it outside the class hence I have changed to public but the array is not visible outside

Comment: Public members defenitely are visible from outside the class. The problem can be if classes are declared in different namespaces.